# Is there a build artefact for the runtime metadata?

Tags: build, metadata

You can download the metadata of a running node by calling the `state_getMetadata` RPC. But if I'm compiling a node, is the metadata built anywhere?
Ideally I'd rather not have to start the node to get the metadata.

Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

The metadata schema is encoded using the SCALE codec library and this encoding is done automatically for you when you compile a node (by using the scale-info crate). So you have to compile the node.

See all the detail information on how to retrieve the metadata in the Substrate Documentation: [Application development](https://docs.substrate.io/build/application-development/)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. It's compiled into the node. Which I stated is already clear - you can use the `state_getMetadata` RPC. The question is not if I have to compile the node, but if I have to *start* the node.